# Backup MSMQ instance in a cluster

Tags: windows, backup, cluster, msmq

I found the right command that allows to backup a MSMQ instance in a server : [mqbkup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mqbkup).

It is working for a local instance but when the MSMQ is in a cluster, I'm not able to make this command works. There is a -c parameter (cluster stuff) to this command but I don't find any documentation about it.

```
PS C:\> mqbkup -b c:\msmqbkup -y -c "ADMSMQUATCLUST01.alterdomus.lu"
Verifying backup privileges
Checking backup directory
Deleting files from folder 'c:\msmqbkup\'
Can't open a handle to cluster resource 'ADMSMQUATCLUST01.alterdomus.lu'
5007
The cluster resource could not be found.
```

The [Failover Cluster Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K53TY.png)

The recent cluster events are not linked to the backup.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong resource name and needed to add 'MSMQ-' as a prefix.

```
mqbkup -b c:\msmqbkup -c 'MSMQ-ADMSMQINSTUAT01'
```